# Split Large File Into Blocks Based on Regex Criteria

Tags: python, regex, file, python-re

I have a large file filled with content in the following pattern. I would like to split each email block. Criteria for a block is that everything from `Subject:`  to second occurrence of `Subject:`  only if it is followed by `From:`.

```
Subject: Hello
From: John Doe
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:13:51 +0200
Lorem ipsum...

Subject: How are you.
I am fine

Subject: Howdy
From: Jane Doe
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:58:14 +0200
Lorem ipsum...

Subject: Re: Howdy
From: Eminem
```

In the example above, first email block would be:

```
Subject: Hello
From: John Doe
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:13:51 +0200
Lorem ipsum...

Subject: How are you.
I am fine
```

Second email block:

```
Subject: Howdy
From: Jane Doe
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:58:14 +0200
Lorem ipsum...
```

I have tried the following method but it doesn't work for all the cases.

`email_blocks = re.split(r'\n(?=Subject:)', email_data)`

It incorrectly splits the first block into two separate blocks because it only looks for the keyword `Subject:`. What I need is a way to split from `Subject:` to second `Subject:` only if followed by `From:`.

I have also tried the following but it didn't create an array of blocks. It only returned the last block:

`email_blocks = re.findall(r'Subject:.*?(?=Subject:|\nFrom:|$)', email_data, re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.split(r'\n(?=Subject:.*\nFrom:)', str)` splits on a newline, looking ahead for a "Subject:", followed by anything, followed by a newline then a "From:"

```
# Output:
['Subject: Hello\nFrom: John Doe\nDate: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:13:51 +0200\nLorem ipsum...\nSubject: How are you.\nI am fine', 
 'Subject: Howdy\nFrom: Jane Doe\nDate: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:58:14 +0200\nLorem ipsum...', 
 'Subject: Re: Howdy\nFrom: Eminem']
```

Comment: Doesnt work properly.

Comment: can you be more specific? That's quite vague. What's the problem?

Comment: ```['', 'Subject: Hello\nFrom: John Doe\nDate: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:13:51 +0200\nLorem ipsum...\n\n', 'Subject: How are you.\nI am fine\n\n', 'Subject: Howdy\nFrom: Jane Doe\nDate: Fri, 12 Feb 2010 09:58:14 +0200\nLorem ipsum...\n\n', 'Subject: Re: Howdy\nFrom: Eminem']```

Comment: Thats the one. Lol I wanted the answer to this one too. I dont use python re too often. But thank you <3

Comment: Shouldn't `.*` be `[^\n]*`?

Comment: @MatBailie those are equivalent (assuming there's no `(?s)` flag)